# oracle sql function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, parameters

```
create or replace function sum(a in number , b in number) 
return number as ans number; begin ans:=a+b; return ans; end;/

begin dbms_output.put_line('Ans is '||sum(10,20)) end;/
```

whats wrong in above code please help

Comment: 'Sum' is probably a reserved word.

Comment: SUM was a reserved word in SQL-92, but not in later versions of the ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the function itself.

Comment: You forget the `;` in your block code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the schema as with these examples:

```
create or replace function sum(a in number , b in number) 
return number as ans number; begin ans:=a+b; return ans; end;/

select ('Ans is '||sum(10,20)) from dual;
```

Returns error, however

```
select ('Ans is '||sum(10+20)) from dual;
```

Returns: Ans is 30

```
select ('Ans is '||sh.sum(10,20)) from dual;
```

Returns: Ans is 30

```
create or replace function suma(a in number , b in number) 
return number as ans number; begin ans:=a+b; return ans; end;/

select ('Ans is '||suma(10,20)) from dual;
```

Returns: Ans is 30

Answer (score 0):

The function is correctly created but because sum is already a function in the database that function is called in your test code instead of the function you just created.

You can call the function but you have to specify the schema as well.

```
begin
   dbms_output.put_line('Ans is ' || my_schema.sum(10, 20));
end;
```

Replace my_schema in the above code with the username under which you compiled the function.